Loading services with different fields using ServiceLoader in Java
I am trying to use Service loader to load all the implementations of an Interface. However I am not unable get it working when Service implementation has private fields.
Here are my service and implementation setup.
public interface OrderProcessor {
  
    void process()
            
}

And in implentation, I need this field to be initialised.
public class OrderProcessorImpl implements OrderProcessor {

    private final int maxOrders;
    

    public OrderStreamProcessorImpl(int maxOrders) {
        this.maxOrders = maxOrders;
    }


    @Override
    public void process() throws IOException {
       // Logic which involves maxOrders.

    }
}

Here's how I am trying to load this service using ServiceLoaderAPI.
public OrderProcessor createProcessor(int maxOrders) {
        var factories =
                ServiceLoader.load(OrderProcessor.class);

        if(factories.hasNext()){
            return factories.next();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No OrderProcessor found");
        }

    }

I also tried using
public static OrderProcessorImpl provider()

but this doesnt work with params.
How do I solve this issue ? Or ServiceLoader API is not the right option in this use case?
Thanks

You have missed out a factory interface which enables the service to create instances of an order processor. See details of ServiceLoader.
You would need two interfaces defining the service, for the factory and a processor. The ServiceLoader will provide instances of all registered Factory implementations:
public interface OrderProcessor {
    void process() throws IOException;
}

public interface OrderProcessorFactory {
    OrderProcessor createProcessor(int maxOrders);
}

Then you can implement 2 classes supporting the factory and processor:
public class OrderProcessorFactoryImpl implements OrderProcessorFactory {

    public OrderProcessorFactoryImpl() {
        System.out.println("OrderProcessorFactoryImpl()");
    }

    public OrderProcessor createProcessor(int maxOrders)
    {
        System.out.println("OrderProcessorFactoryImpl.createProcessor("+maxOrders+")");
        return new OrderProcessorImpl(maxOrders);
    }
}

public class OrderProcessorImpl implements OrderProcessor {

    private final int maxOrders;

    public OrderProcessorImpl(int maxOrders) {
        System.out.println("OrderProcessorImpl("+maxOrders+")");
        this.maxOrders = maxOrders;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("OrderProcessorImpl.process() where maxOrders is "+maxOrders);
    }
}

Add a file META-INF/services/packagenameof.theinterface.OrderProcessorFactory to register your implementation which contains one line:
yourpackage.OrderProcessorFactoryImpl

Then you can lookup a factory and instantiate an order processor:
ServiceLoader<OrderProcessorFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(OrderProcessorFactory.class);
System.out.println("loader="+loader);

for (OrderProcessorFactory factory : loader) {
    OrderProcessor max999 = factory.createProcessor(999);
    System.out.println("max999="+max999);
    if (max999 != null)
        max999.process();
}

Should print:
loader=java.util.ServiceLoader[stackoverflow.service.OrderFactory]
OrderFactoryImpl()
OrderFactoryImpl.createProcessor(999)
OrderProcessorImpl(999)
max999=yourpackage.OrderProcessorImpl@7699a589
OrderProcessorImpl.process maxOrders=999


Haven't we made the factory and the other object tightly coupled?
Also, If there are more instances of OrderProcessor, How would we load them using the factory?

You don't need a factory scheme as above, spi with void process(int order) would have been simpler.  In this particular example the factory can create multiple OrderProcessor instances, or you can register multiple factories for different implementations.

There is some dependency between factory and implementations but that does not prevent having other implementations. For example java.sql.Driver SPI is setup such that you can access a Connection from a url string, and obviously Oracle JDBC driver must be able to serve different Connection implementation to SQL Server drivers.
